# Firebase Cloud Messaging Localization Arguments Error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am providing the following Payload to `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, message);`

```
var message = {
    notification: {
      title_loc_key: "NOTIFICATION_TITLE",
      body_loc_key: "NOTIFICATION_BODY",
      body_loc_args: ["Body Arg"],
      sound: 'default'
    }
};
```

However this generates the following error:

```
Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.body_loc_args" property. Values must be strings.
```

I don't see how "Body Arg" is not a string. I also tried specifying a string but this also did not work...

Any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of the Admin SDK is being used, but if the code is on the latest, then only `title` and `body` go in the `notification` object. Other values go under the `payload` key. [Here's an example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#apns_specific_fields) in the guide. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig) is the API reference. Your message variable should look somewhat like this:

```
var message = {
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        alert: {
          title_loc_key: "NOTIFICATION_TITLE",
          body_loc_key: "NOTIFICATION_BODY",
          body_loc_args: ["Body Arg"],
          sound: 'default'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

If the code doesn't use the latest version of the Admin SDK, I recommend updating.

Comment: I am getting Messaging payload contains an invalid "apns" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification". Also wrapping it in a notification thing does not work. And I am using the latest admin sdk in a cloud function

Comment: You should be using `send`, not `sendToDevice` to use FCM v1. The device token should be inn the body of the function as shown in the guide I linked.

Comment: No problem! Glad you posted this because it actually did help me find a bug in the docs :)