# Firebase Cloud Messaging localization arguments for iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to compose localized push notifications for iOS with FCM. I can't figure out the correct format of the message. This how I'm formatting it right now:

```
async function sendLocationLostNotification(notificationToken: string, newOwner: string, locationName: string) {
    const message = {
        name: "Location Lost Notification",
        token: notificationToken,
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    alert: {
                        loc_key: "location-lost-notification-body",
                        loc_args: [newOwner, locationName]

                    },
                    sound: "default"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return await admin.messaging().send(message)
}
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
src/index.ts:109:41 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ name: string; token: string; apns: { payload: { aps: { alert: { loc_key: string; loc_args: string[]; }; sound: string; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Message'.
  Type '{ name: string; token: string; apns: { payload: { aps: { alert: { loc_key: string; loc_args: string[]; }; sound: string; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'TokenMessage'.
    Types of property 'apns' are incompatible.
      Type '{ payload: { aps: { alert: { loc_key: string; loc_args: string[]; }; sound: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ApnsConfig'.
        Types of property 'payload' are incompatible.
          Type '{ aps: { alert: { loc_key: string; loc_args: string[]; }; sound: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ApnsPayload'.
            Types of property 'aps' are incompatible.
              Type '{ alert: { loc_key: string; loc_args: string[]; }; sound: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Aps'.
                Types of property 'alert' are incompatible.
                  Type '{ loc_key: string; loc_args: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | ApsAlert | undefined'.
                    Type '{ loc_key: string; loc_args: string[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'ApsAlert'.

109     return await admin.messaging().send(message)
```

I've read [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html) about the correct payload format which is referenced to from the [Firebase API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#ApnsConfig). Also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51107845/7620962) about a similar problem but Jen Person's suggested format gives me the same error as I'm facing now. The only way I'm able to silence it is to add either `title` or `body` to the alert object, but that overrides the loc-keys. So it seems those keys are mandatory. Furthermore, I've tried using `body_loc_key` and `title_loc_key` separately, and all at once, but with no luck.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `ApsAlert` uses `locKey` and `locArgs` according to [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.ApsAlert.html).

Comment: URL returns 404.